# JSON serialization/deserialization not working when migrating to ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We are migrating a site from ASP MVC .Net Framework to .Net Core. In many cases we do ajax POST requests from the page to the Controller:

#### js:

```js
var request = { Name: "bar" };
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/foo",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(request),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log();
    }
});
```

#### c# Controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> foo(FooRequest request)
{
    //request.Name is empty
    return Json(new { msg = "Success" });
}
```

#### c# Model:

```cs
public class FooRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This all works in .Net Framework, but fails in Core **were all properties of the received object are null**.

I've tried using both `AddJsonOptions`:

```cs
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddJsonOptions(option =>
    {
        option.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
        option.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
    });
```

...and `AddNewtonsoftJson`:

```cs
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(option =>
    {
        option.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
    });
```

...but none of them works.

### What do I need to do to get the same behavior in .Net Core as I do in .Net Framework?

### Update

I get the same behavior calling the endoint from Postman (request.Name is null):

```
POST /home/foo HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44393
Content-Type: application/json

{ "Name": "bar" }
```

I've also tried to serializing the request:

```js
var request = { Name: "bar" };
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/foo",
    type: "POST",
    data: request,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log();
    }
});
```

...but with the same result

Comment: Should have been more clear, but all properties of the received object are null.

Comment: Did you check what you're POSTing? Why are you calling JSON.stringify on the object you're posting?

Comment: Because that was the only way to get it to work in .Net Framework. I'd be happy to change that, but I get the same issue using data:request,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the `FromBodyAttribute` to your parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> foo([FromBody] FooRequest request)
{
    //request.Name is empty
    return Json(new { msg = "Success" });
}
```

You can omit this attribute, if you decorate your controller with the `ApiControllerAttribute`

Comment: Thanks...Just one short question is there a way to set this in the Startup.cs, as I've got a lot of these type of methods (residing my normal Actions)?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The only "global"-ish way is to use ApiControllers for Http requests, and normal controllers for views. So if you refactor your api call inside a controller with decorated with [ApiController], you should be able to omit this.

Comment: You can probably do it with an action filter.